# qTip2 - change which tooltip content is used on class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, qtip2

I am using qTip2, and I have a list of links that have tooltips on them. I read tooltips content from an attribute in my link called "data-normal". There is a checkbox next to each link, and when it's clicked it removes the class for that link and adds some other class. When the link is changed like that, I would like the tooltip to stay but to be read from a different attribute ("data-changed").

Also, when the box is unchecked (and classes reverted) I would like it to function like before the change.

Is there a solution for this?

Here is the piece of code I use for this:

```
$('.normal').qtip({
    content: {
    text: function(api) {
        return $(this).attr('data-normal');
        }
    }
});

$('.changed').qtip({
    content: {
    text: function(api) {
        return $(this).attr('data-changed');
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/trunkadelic/Xkvnt/1/

This is of course a simplified example of what I'm trying to do on the website itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a").qtip({
    content: {
        text: function(api) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('changed')) {
                return $(this).attr('data-changed');
            } else {
                return $(this).attr('data-normal');

            }
        }
    }
});
```

this should work. Here is your updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xkvnt/5/

Comment: Thank you, this is how I ended up doing it, too. I also needed to change the tooltip position, so if anyone else wants to know:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xkvnt/3/